# Quartz.NET Push forward/pull back time on a daily schedule

Tags: quartz.net, schedule

I've recently come across Quartz.net, and would like to know the best approach on setting up daily (weekday) tasks. So let's say a bunch of tasks needs to run daily from 2-5pm, and at times I'd like to bring it forward, or push it back by 30 minutes.

At the moment I'm thinking of iterating through all the daily scheduled jobs, and adjusting the trigger. Delete/recreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you have 2 options:

1. Reschedule the jobs' triggers. It's basically a delete+recreate of
   the trigger, but there is a method that does it for you:
   http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic920.html
2. Create a job that will schedule the other tasks for you every day
   (or whenever you know whether you want to change the time or not).
   This jobs could potentially create jobs for several days in advance
   if you know in advance what the schedule might be.

If the changes to the schedule don't happen very often, I'd go with option #1. If, on the other hand, you change the schedule often, I'd go with #2.